# How to call a Vuex method from life cycles

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have the following function in Vuex actions:

```
async toggleNavMenu({commit}){
  commit('changeNavMenu')
}
```

which just changes `state.ShowNavMenu` status from true to false and vise versa. I'm trying to call it the moment `SignUp.vue` component render to hide the NavMenu, like this

```
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'
export default {
  name:"NavMenu",
  methods:{
    ...mapActions({
      Toggle: actions => actions.toggleNavMenu
        })
      },
    beforeCreate() {
      this.Toggle()
  }
}
```

but when ever I render the component I get the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined"
```

any idea to fix this, or if there a better approach for this ? thanks in advance

Comment: could you show us the place where this error occured? where does it try to dispatch something?

Comment: could you try different lifecycle hook? For example created(). Vuex store is probably not yet initialized in beforeCreate()

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.Change the life cycle from `beforeCreate()` to `created()`
and change:

```
  ...mapActions({
      Toggle: actions => actions.toggleNavMenu
    })
```

to:

```
  ...mapActions({
     Toggle: 'toggleNavMenu'
  })
```

I don't why I had to change `Toggle` assignment like this though